# Error when changing my calendarID away from 'primary'?

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I would like to add an event to a specific calendar on my google calendar account. If I change the calendarid away from 'primary' then I get an error.

The calendar I would like specifically to add to is called "MyCal"
I have tried replacing 'primary' with 'MyCal'. I have also tried making my calendar public and copying the id from the share link, but I still get a "404...Not Found" error. I am using the example code. If the calendarid is set to 'primary' then it works. My line to add an event is at the very bottom. I also attached the error. Thanks!

```
from __future__ import print_function
import datetime
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']

def main():
"""Shows basic usage of the Google Calendar API.
Prints the start and name of the next 10 events on the user's calendar.
"""
creds = None
# The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
# created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
# time.
if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
    with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
        creds = pickle.load(token)
# If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server()
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
        pickle.dump(creds, token)

service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)

# Call the Calendar API
now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z' # 'Z' indicates UTC time
print('Getting the upcoming 10 events')
events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=now,
                                    maxResults=10, singleEvents=True,
                                    orderBy='startTime').execute()
events = events_result.get('items', [])

if not events:
    print('No upcoming events found.')
for event in events:
    start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
    print(start, event['summary'])

event = {
    'summary': 'Google I/O 2015',
    'location': '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
    'description': 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
    'start': {
        'dateTime': '2019-05-28T09:00:00-07:00',
        'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
    },
    'end': {
        'dateTime': '2019-05-28T17:00:00-07:00',
        'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
    },
    'reminders': {
        'useDefault': False,
        'overrides': [
            {'method': 'email', 'minutes': 24 * 60},
            {'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 10},
        ],
    },
}
event = service.events().insert(calendarId='MyCal', body=event).execute()
```

if **name** == '**main**':
    main()

[image]

[image]

Comment: It works! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are trying to use `summary` as the calendar ID. Although in the case of `primary`, `primary` can be used as the calendar ID because `id` and `summary` is the same, the calendar ID of `MyCal` is different from `summary`. By this, such error occurs.

So please use the calendar ID. For example, as one of several methods, you can retrieve the calendar ID at [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list?apix_params=%7B%22fields%22%3A%22items(id%2Cprimary%2Csummary)%22%7D). When you click "EXECUTE" button, you can see the following result.

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "id": "### calendar ID ###",
   "summary": "MyCal"
  },
  {
   "id": "### email ###",
   "summary": "### email ###",
   "primary": true
  }
 ]
}
```

Please use `id` of `MyCal` as the calendar ID and try again.

#### References:

- [CalendarList: list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list)
- [Events: insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.